# Does anyone have a working example for serverside datagrid pagination of Clarity?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Does anyone have a working example for serverside datagrid pagination of Clarity?
Please share me a stackblitz or plunker link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-dg-server-driven

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The Clarity website has one such example but here is the full example that you could use. Note it doesn't call a server, but it does the same thing by creating and destroying the array (which happens with an API call).

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/dev/src/app/datagrid/server-driven